# Extend HashMap to get all objects with the specified hashcode?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

From what I understand, when two objects are put in a HashMap that have the same hashcode, they are put in a LinkedList (I think) of objects with the same hash code. I am wondering if there is a way to either extend HashMap or manipulate the existing methods to return a list or array of objects that share a hash code instead of going into equals to see if they are the same object.

The reasoning is that I'm trying to optimize a part of a code that, currently, is just a while loop that finds the first object with that hashcode and stores/removes it. This would be a lot faster if I could just return the full list in one go.

Here's the bit of code I'd like to replace:

```
    while (WorkingMap.containsKey(toSearch)) { 
        Occurences++;
        Possibles.add(WorkingMap.get(toSearch));
        WorkingMap.remove(toSearch);
    }
```

The keys are Chunk objects and the values are Strings. Here are the hashcode() and equals() functions for the Chunk class:

```
 /**
 * Returns a string representation of the ArrayList of words
 * thereby storing chunks with the same words but with different
 * locations and next words in the same has bucket, triggering the
 * use of equals() when searching and adding
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return (Words.toString()).hashCode();
}

@Override
/**
 * result depends on the value of location. A location of -1 is obviously
 * not valid and therefore indicates that we are searching for a match rather
 * than adding to the map. This allows multiples of keys with matching hashcodes 
 * to be considered unequal when adding to the hashmap but equal when searching
 * it, which is integral to the MakeMap() and GetOptions() methods of the 
 * RandomTextGenerator class.
 * 
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Chunk tempChunk = (Chunk)obj;
    if (LocationInText == -1 && Words.size() == tempChunk.GetText().size())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Words.size(); i++) {
            if (!Words.get(i).equals(tempChunk.GetText().get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (tempChunk.GetLocation() == LocationInText) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about using like a `Map<Location, List<Chunk>>`?

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how that would be useful in this case? I considered Map and TreeMap but didn't see them as useful. Is there a way to retrieve all objects of the same value that way?

Comment: Honestly I don't entirely understand what your data structure actually looks like (you don't include a declaration for the map) except for the way you're misusing the `HashMap` keys. But it seems pretty clear to me that what you're trying to get is a `Map<..., List<...>>` so just use that instead of misusing the implementation details of `HashMap` to simulate it.

Comment: Please also take a look at http://xyproblem.info. You've asked us about your attempted solution but not told us anything about the problem you're actually trying to solve, so we can't accurately suggest a proper alternative.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` does not expose any way to do this, but I think you're misunderstanding how `HashMap` works in the first place.

The first thing you need to know is that if *every single object* had exactly the same hash code, `HashMap` would still work.  It would never "mix up" keys.  If you call `get(key)`, it will only return the value associated with `key`.

The reason this works is that `HashMap` only uses `hashCode` as a first grouping, but *then* it checks the object you passed to `get` against the keys stored in the map using the `.equals` method.

There is no way, from the outside, to tell that `HashMap` uses linked lists.  (In fact, in more recent versions of Java, it *doesn't* always use linked lists.)  The implementation doesn't provide any way to look at hash codes, to find out how hash codes are grouped, or anything along those lines.

> ```
> while (WorkingMap.containsKey(toSearch)) { 
>     Occurences++;
>     Possibles.add(WorkingMap.get(toSearch));
>     WorkingMap.remove(toSearch);
> }
> ```

This code does not "find the first object with that hashcode and store/remove it."  It finds the one and only object *equal to* `toSearch` according to `.equals`, stores and removes it.  (There can only be one such object in a `Map`.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but the equals() method I defined and included does work the way I described, even though a HashMap does not automatically work that way. I made it so that if the "Location" characteristic of toSearch is -1, it returns true as long as the hashcodes match. If the location is >-1, it actually checks for equality. I hope that makes sense. So I'm wondering if I can get all the objects with equal hashcodes at once, essentially making it so instead of calling equals(), get() just returns any and all objects with the hashcode of the argument. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @AlexxMurphy, if you defined `equals` that way, then when you put in an object with a hash code that's already there, it will _overwrite and erase_ the object with the hash code that was already in the map.  You cannot have two different `equals` objects in the map at once; you cannot make `HashMap` do what you're trying to do, and frankly there's no good reason to.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry it's difficult to explain. Basically, when populating the hashmap, equals() works as it should- actually seeing if the objects are equal. But when using .get() or .containsKey(), I set the location of the object toSearch to -1. In the equals() function above, you can see that if the location is -1, equals returns true as long as the words match. If location is not -1, it only returns true if location also matches. So when you push an entry, the location will not be -1, and therefore equals() will return false and not override the object.

Comment: @AlexxMurphy what you're doing is a terrible idea.  No, there is no way to abuse `HashMap` in the way you're trying to, and you really really shouldn't be doing that kind of hackery.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on what to use instead, then?

Comment: You should never modify objects that are keys in a `HashMap`, and your `equals` method should always be symmetric.  Frankly, it looks like what you should be doing is just iterating over the `HashMap` searching for matches rather than trying to abuse `HashMap` into doing what you want.  You should _not_ try having the magic `equals` behavior you're going for.

Comment: I mean, at that point I might as well use an ArrayList or something. I know for a fact there is a more efficient way to do this, and I know it involves using HashMap.

Comment: @AlexxMurphy what makes you so sure?

Comment: It is an assignment for class where we get more points for efficiency. The assignment states that doing what you described with iteration is an O(s*g) time complexity, while there is a possible solution using a hashmap that is O(s + g) complexity.

Comment: Ah, I think @Radiodef got it in the comments up above.  Instead of having a magic `equals` method, you should be having a map from locations to all the chunks with that location, it looks like?  It's hard to tell when you haven't told us what the actual goal is.

Comment: Yeah I feel like I considered that at one point but I'm not sure why I decided against it. I'll look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your while isn't really going. It makes max one turn, if the WorkingMap is a plain Java `HashMap`. `.get(key)` return the last saved Object in the `HashMap` that is saved on `'key'`. If it matched `toSearch`, than it going once.

I'm not sure about that many open questions here. But if you need that one and your farther code is understanding

What kind of type is `class Possibles`? `ArrayList`?

```
 // this one should make the same as your while
        if(WorkingMap.containsKey(toSearch)) {
           Possibles.add(WorkingMap.get(toSearch));
           WorkingMap.remove(toSearch);
        }

// farher: expand your Possibles to get that LinkedList what you want to have. 
    public class possibilities {

            // List<LinkedList<String>> container = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>();
            public Map<Chunk, LinkedList<String>> container2 = new HashMap<Chunk, LinkedList<String>>();

            public void put(Chunk key, String value) {
                if(!this.container2.containsKey(key)) {
                    this.container2.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
                }
                this.container2.get(key).add(value);
            }

        }
    // this one works with updated Possibles
        if(WorkingMap.containsKey(toSearch)) {
           Possibles.put(toSearch, WorkingMap.get(toSearch));
           WorkingMap.remove(toSearch);
        }
//---
```

How ever, yes it can go like that, but keys should not be a complex object.

Notice: That LinkedLists takes memory and how big are chunks? check Memory Usage

```
Possibles.(get)container2.keySet();
```

Good Look

Sail

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, when two objects are put in a HashMap that have the same hashcode, they are put in a LinkedList (I think) of objects with the same hash code.

Yes, but it's more complicated than that. It often needs to put objects in linked lists even when they have differing hash codes, since it only uses *some bits* of the hash codes to choose which bucket to store objects in; the number of bits it uses depends on the current size of the internal hash table, which approximately depends on the number of things in the map. And when a bucket needs to contain multiple objects it will also try to use binary trees like a `TreeMap` if possible (if objects are mutually `Comparable`), rather than linked lists.

*Anyway.....*

> I am wondering if there is a way to either extend HashMap or manipulate the existing methods to return a list or array of objects that share a hash code instead of going into equals to see if they are the same object.

No.

A `HashMap` compares keys for *equality* according to the `equals` method. Equality according to the `equals` method is the *only* valid way to set, replace, or retrieve values associated with a particular key.

Yes, it also uses `hashCode` as a way to arrange objects in a structure that allows for far faster location of potentially equal objects. Still, [the contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) for matching keys is defined in terms of `equals`, not `hashCode`.

Note that it is perfectly legal for every `hashCode` method to be implemented as `return 0;` and the map will still work just as correctly (but very slowly). So any idea that involves getting a list of objects sharing a hash code is either impossible or pointless or both.

---

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing in your `equals` method with the `LocationInText` variable, but it looks dangerous, as it violates the contract of the `equals` method. It is *required* that the [`equals` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) be symmetric, transitive, and consistent:

> - *Symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.
> - *Transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns true and `y.equals(z)` returns true, then `x.equals(z)` should return true.
> - *Consistent*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the objects is modified.

And the [`hashCode` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) is required to always agree with `equals` about equal objects:

> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

The `LocationInText` variable is playing havoc with those rules, and may well break things. If not today, then some day. **Get rid of it!**

> Here's the bit of code I'd like to replace:
>
> ```
>   while (WorkingMap.containsKey(toSearch)) { 
>       Occurences++;
>       Possibles.add(WorkingMap.get(toSearch));
>       WorkingMap.remove(toSearch);
>   }
> ```

Something that jumps out at me is that you only need to do the key lookup once, instead of doing it three times, since `Map.remove` returns the removed value or null if the key is not present:

```
for (;;) {
    String s = WorkingMap.remove(toSearch);
    if (s == null) break;
    Occurences++;
    Possibles.add(s);
}
```

Either way, the loop is still faulty, since it is supposed to be impossible for a map to contain more than one key equal to `toSearch`. I can't overstate that the `LocationInText` variable as you're using it is not a good idea.

I agree with the other commenters it looks like you're looking for a map-of-list structure. Some Java libraries like Guava offer a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for this, but you can do it manually pretty easily. I think the declaration you want is:

```
Map<Chunk,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

To add a new chunk-string pair to the map, do:

```
void add(Chunk chunk, String string) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(chunk, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(string);
}
```

That method puts a new `ArrayList` in the map if the chunk is new, or fetches the existing `ArrayList` if there is one for that chunk. Then it adds the string to the list that it fetched or created.

To retrieve the list of all strings for a particular chunk value is as simple as `map.get(chunkToSearch)`, which you can add to your `Possibles` list as `Possibles.addAll(map.get(chunkToSearch));`.

Other potential optimizations I'd point out:

- In your `Chunk.hashCode` method, consider caching the hash code instead of recomputing it every time the method is called. If `Chunk` is mutable (which is not a good idea for a map key, but vaguely allowed so long as you're careful) then recompute the hash code only after the `Chunk`'s value has changed. Also, if `Words` is a `List`, which it seems to be, it would likely be faster to use its hash code than convert it to a string and use the string's hash code, but I'm not sure.
- In your `Chunk.equals` method, you can return `true` immediately if the instances are the same (which they often will be). Also, if `GetText` returns a copy of the data, then don't call it; you can access the private `Words` list of the other `Chunk` since you are in the same class, and finally, you can just defer to the `List.equals` method:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return (this == o) || (o instanceof Chunk && this.Words.equals(((Chunk)o).Words));
  }
  ```

  Simple! Fast!